# Hibernate Cascade at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm not sure if I'm asking the question the way it should be 
but I am trying to create a new account in my project and for that method I want my USER Entity to be `CascadeType.ALL` , but just for this creating account method only. Not for any other method using the USER class.

Like if I want to use `FetchType.LAZY` at the run time for some particular method I implement it in criteria as `criteria.setFetchType.LAZY` and not inside my Entity.

In the same way,  can I implement `CascadeType.ALL` at the run time of my application?

Here is my entity class in which i am Applying Cascade, its working fine

```
public Class UserEntity implements Serializable

    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name="teamId")
    private TeamEntity teamId;
}
```

Here is my method in which i am using this cascade functionality , Now i just want this cascade functionality to define inside this method and remove from the entity

Is that possible ?

```
public String addTeam(UserEntity userInfoEntity) throws Exception{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(UserInfoEntity.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set cascade to `@Cascade({ CascadeType.Save })` then only save operations (which are only happen in creating the user right?) will cascade.

Comment: thanks , it works for save,update , but now my delete query is not working , any idea ..

Comment: i interpreted the question that you do not want to cascade except this one special case. if you need cascade the set it to all. AFAIK it is not possible to override this behaviour at runtime and i never ever saw a use case which needed that.